# How to remove Warning message that lingers after switching from Parse 1.6.2 to a later version

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I switched from `Parse 1.6.2` to `1.7.1`. I replaced the old Parse framework with the new one. However, the build process appears to be looking for the old library. Please guide me where I would find the reference to the old framework

> (null): Directory not found for option
>   '-/Documents/Development/iOS/parse-library-1.6.2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place to look might be in your project or target settings.  Scroll down through them and see if you can find where "`parse-library-1.6.2`" might be included.

And then delete it.

Here's where you can look go hunting for that bogus path:
[image: Project Settings]

And in general, you should not keep files used by your project in folders outside (e.g. "`~/Documents`") of your source code hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I located the reference and deleted it and it cleared the warning. Unfortunately, I am now getting a message "No such module" on import Parse even though the Framework is clearly in the list of frameworks. I am going through the build settings to locate if there is a bad reference,

Comment: CORRECTION: I removed the Parse framework and then re-added it to correct the problem.